# MAMP Pro (MacOS) host can't connect using https.. "Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER "

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to configure one localhost using MAMP Pro (6.x) on MacOS. The SSL checkbox is also yes but when I load the site, it shows "Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER" in the Firefox and same error in console of Chrome.
Attached are the error screenshots from Chrome, Firefox and localhost settings from MAMP Pro.

Stack info

- MAMP Pro 6.x.
- Mac OS Monterey
- WordPress (siturl and homeurl in DB are using https. wp-config.php forcing https too)
- hostname: movecn.dev

**What I tried till now?**

- Tried Self-signed certificate
- Tried ports (80, 443, 8890)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it after spending hours and hours. MAMP / MAMP pro creates "MAMP_PRO_Root_CA" which suppose to be added and trusted in MACos keychain. It will be used to sign all the future/custom SSL certs.

In my case, "MAMP_PRO_Root_CA" was already added in the keychain but it was not trusted by the system. Steps to resolve.

- Open Keychain Access and click "System Root" left side
- Click "Certificates" on the top and then search for "MAMP_PRO_Root_CA" select and click "Get info"
- In Trust section/dropdown, choose "always trust"
- close it. (It may ask for your password etc)
- Close and restart your browser.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! I also had to select the Certificate file and Certificate key file of MAMP_PRO_Root_CA in the "SSL" tab of the host.